# jquery ui datepicker not displaying on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the jquery ui datepicker in my asp.net website.The datepicker works fine when I run it from Visual Studio on my machine.However,when I host it on IIS on the Test server,the datepicker does not display.My aspx page looks like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".txtDatepicker").datepicker({
                minDate:0,
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonText: "Calendar",
                buttonImage: 'calendar.gif'
            });
        });
```

I am trying to display the datepicker inside a gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUnitsData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDataBound="grdUnitsData_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="false" RowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="LightBlue"  BorderStyle="Solid">
    <RowStyle Height="5px" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle Height="5px" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Identity" Visible="false"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Unit Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Unit Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>Start Date</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" style="min-width: 25px;" class="txtDatepicker" Text='<%#Eval("StartDate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField>
           <HeaderTemplate>End Date</HeaderTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" style="min-width: 25px;" class="txtDatepicker" Text='<%#Eval("EndDate")%>'></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Things I have tried:**

1. Using `showOn:'both'` instead of `showOn:'button'`

Comment: use document.ready ...

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla :- Tried that...didnt work. As I've mentioned,the datepicker works in IE but not in Chrome and Firefox. Any other ideas?

Comment: `$function () {` should be `$(function(){})` instead

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason, but try using the CssClass property of Asp.net textbox control.

Comment: @HanletEscaño :- Thanks for your help.But the problem is:the datepicker works on all the browsers when I run it from within Visual Studio on my computer.The datepicker(calendar image+button) does not appear on Chrome and Firefox when I deploy the website on the server,it only appears in IE.